# Storing subtype objects in a list in AppEngine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, subclass

I'm trying to create single list of sequenced objects using the data store API.
(the reason its in one list is because the objects are ordered when written - its basically like a glorified LOG file).

My issue is that the things i want to store in the list are sub types of an interface/abstract class i've defined.

I have a current store using my SQL, which looks like: 
ID, Group ID, Sequence Number, Serialized String of subclass.

I was hoping by pushing this into data store i would not have to Serialize, and could instead store the objects. But im now a little unsure as the best approach here.

nb. Im using the direct data store API, not JDO/JPA etc.

I guess one option is to continue to Serialize - im not clear how good the support is for various serialization methods on AppEngine?  I guess i can store as byte array - writing directly with the serialzable interface?

Or, i can store some master meta list, and store each object sub type as its own Entity - im not sure able referencing this back, and speed implications? I have around 100 different sub types im needing to store.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

It seems like a pretty fundamental issue - one i presumed would be naturally no problem with a noSQL data store - but im new to this whole concept - im a relational database man until this point :)

thanks!!

***UPDATE / EDIT***

mm, ive just re-read the documentation page for Entities/querying etc... and i think i maybe falling into the relational database thinker trap...

A section under Entities states:

Note: Datastore entities are schemaless: unlike traditional relational databases, the App Engine Datastore does not require that all entities of a given kind have the same properties or that all of an entity's values for a given property be of the same data type. If a formal schema is needed, the application itself is responsible for ensuring that entities conform to it; the Python SDK includes a rich library of data modeling features for this purpose.

I think that means i can store all my sub classes under the "Entity" reference of the Interface eg..

Class A extends Z

Class B extends Z

Save Class A and B as Entity "Z". not save as Entity A and Entity B.

It seems it doesn't care that the majority of properties etc are completely different :)

Is this right - for sanity, can anyone verify this is indeed what is expected in such a scenario ?